# How can I format clipboard data in Javascript to create soft line breaks when pasted into MS Word?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, clipboard, clipboarddata

In Javascript, I am putting billing/shipping address data on the clipboard (using clipboard.js).  When I paste that data into MS Word, it shows up with paragraph separators and looks too spread out for an address.

How can I format the data from Javascript so it shows up as if each line ended with a soft line break (press shift-Enter in MS Word) when I paste the data into MS Word?

Comment: You'd need to replace ANSI 13 (or possibly 10 + 13, if that's what's being put on the clipboard) with ANSI 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been joining the lines with linefeed:

```
copyText = copyText.join('\n');
```

I just changed `\n` to `\v` (vertical tab):

```
copyText = copyText.join('\v');
```

Comment: btw thanks to @Cindy Meister and this site for helping me figure out the encoding: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm